# PySpark get value of previous group

Tags: python, pyspark

I'm trying to get the previous value within the same group, using a dataframe and PySpark, but i'm unable to get this to work when the group consists of two columns (date and text)

```
window = Window.partitionBy("date", "text").orderBy("date", "text")
df2 = df2.withColumn('prev_date', func.lag(df2['count']).over(window))
```

Resulting in:

```
+--------+----+-----+---+----------+
|    date|text|count|day|prev_count|
+--------+----+-----+---+----------+
|20180901| cat|    2|  1|      null|
|20180901| dog|    2|  1|      null|
|20180902| cat|    3|  2|      null|
|20180902| dog|    6|  2|      null|
|20180903| cat|    2|  3|      null|
|20180904| cat|    3|  4|      null|
|20180905| cat|    2|  5|      null|
|20180905| dog|    4|  5|      null|
+--------+----+-----+---+----------+
```

The desired output:

```
+--------+----+-----+---+----------+
|    date|text|count|day|prev_count|
+--------+----+-----+---+----------+
|20180901| cat|    2|  1|      null|
|20180901| dog|    2|  1|      null|
|20180902| cat|    3|  2|         2|
|20180902| dog|    6|  2|         2|
|20180903| cat|    2|  3|         3|
|20180904| cat|    3|  4|         2|
|20180905| cat|    2|  5|         3|
|20180905| dog|    4|  5|         6|
+--------+----+-----+---+----------+
```

The goal is to compare `text` count from one day to the previous day.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should remove "date" field in partitionBy statement. Data is unique with "date" and "text" fields so it means there is not another same combination again. This is the reason why all values return null

```
>>> from pyspark.sql.window import Window
>>> import pyspark.sql.functions as func
>>> 
>>> data = sc.parallelize([
...     ('20180901','cat',2,1),
...     ('20180901','dog',2,1),
...     ('20180902','cat',3,2),
...     ('20180902','dog',6,2),
...     ('20180903','cat',2,3),
...     ('20180904','cat',3,4),
...     ('20180905','cat',2,5),
...     ('20180905','dog',4,5)])
>>> 
>>> columns = ['date','text','count','day']
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)
>>> 
>>> window = Window.partitionBy('text').orderBy('date','text')
>>> df = df.withColumn('prev_date', func.lag('count').over(window))
>>> 
>>> df.sort('date','text').show()
+--------+----+-----+---+---------+                                             
|    date|text|count|day|prev_date|
+--------+----+-----+---+---------+
|20180901| cat|    2|  1|     null|
|20180901| dog|    2|  1|     null|
|20180902| cat|    3|  2|        2|
|20180902| dog|    6|  2|        2|
|20180903| cat|    2|  3|        3|
|20180904| cat|    3|  4|        2|
|20180905| cat|    2|  5|        3|
|20180905| dog|    4|  5|        6|
+--------+----+-----+---+---------+
```

Comment: If I would like to make it more robust, cses where `text` is missing for specific dates, what would be the approach than?

Comment: df = df.withColumn('prev_cnt', func.lag('count').over(window))
df = df.withColumn('prev_dt', func.lag('date').over(window))
df = df.withColumn('date_diff', func.datediff(func.to_date('date', 'yyyymmdd'),func.to_date('prev_dt', 'yyyymmdd')))
df = df.withColumn('prev_date', func.when(df["date_diff"] == 1, df["prev_cnt"]))
df = df.drop(*["prev_cnt","prev_dt","date_diff"])

df.sort('date','text').show()
Try this